# How to get Docker-Compose to run a shell command before starting IBM-MQ server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ibm-mq

Hey guys so I've been trying to get my docker-compose.yml file to just cat the contents of a local file before it boots up the IBM-MQ server but I can't seem to get the MQ server to work correctly. I have a simple helloworld.txt in the files folder that just consists of HELLO WORLD in it that I'm trying to cat.

```
version: '3'

mq:
    image: ibmcom/mq:latest
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
    environment:
        - LICENSE=accept
        - MQ_QMGR_NAME=MQA01
    volumes:
        - ./files:/var/mqm
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    command: >
      sh -c "cat helloworld.txt"
```

But running docker-compose up gives the below error -

```
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.360Z CPU architecture: amd64
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.360Z Linux kernel version: 4.15.0-20-generic
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.360Z Container runtime: docker
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.361Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.365Z Running as user ID 888 () with primary group 888, and supplementary groups 0
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.365Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.366Z seccomp enforcing mode: filtering
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.366Z Process security attributes: docker-default (enforce)
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.366Z Detected 'ext4' volume mounted to /mnt/mqm/data
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.467Z Set password for "admin" user
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.579Z Using queue manager name: MQA01
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.580Z Error: Unable to change ownership of /mnt/mqm/data
mq_1      | 2019-09-11T18:15:24.580Z chown /mnt/mqm/data: operation not permitted
```

EDIT - I changed volumes to

```
volumes:
        - ./files/helloworld.txt:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/helloworld.txt
```

But now it just seems like the manager runs indefinitely and the shell command cat helloworld.txt is never run.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Unable to change ownership of /mnt/mqm/data

**Running with the default configuration and a volume**

> The above example will not persist any configuration data or messages
>   across container runs. In order to do this, you need to use a volume.
>   For example, you can create a volume with the following command:

`docker volume create qm1data`
You can then run a queue manager using this volume as follows:

```
docker run \
  --env LICENSE=accept \
  --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 \
  --publish 1414:1414 \
  --publish 9443:9443 \
  --detach \
  --volume qm1data:/mnt/mqm \
  ibmcom/mq
```

or after

```
docker volume create qm1data
```

volume once created then

```
    image: ibmcom/mq:latest
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
    environment:
        - LICENSE=accept
        - MQ_QMGR_NAME=MQA01
    volumes:
        - qm1data:/var/mqm
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
```

The Docker image always uses /mnt/mqm for MQ data, which is correctly linked for you under /var/mqm at runtime. **This is to handle problems with file permissions on some platforms.**

[running-with-the-default-configuration-and-a-volume](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker#running-with-the-default-configuration-and-a-volume)

Comment: I'm away from my development laptop at the moment but inside qm1data do I add the local files I want to copy over to /var/mqm? I think I've also seen like a separate volumes: qm1data at the bottom of a docker-compose for instance. Does this achieve the same thing?

Comment: No you need to attached named volume